# Changing AZDO dashboard scope from Team to Project

Tags: azure-devops, tfs

Trying to convert/replace AZDO dashboard from Team to Project scope.
So far i have tried multiple things following the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/dashboard/dashboards/replace-dashboard?view=azure-devops-server-rest-6.0#dashboardscope).
This was just one of the variations.
My server is on Prem and supports API up to 6.1
But it should work, unless if am missing something crucial here.
I am using PAT with Full Access.
Name and ID is correct.

Error i am getting:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4rQo.png)

```
$organization = "Myorg"
$project = "DummyProject"
$teamId = "TeamId# here"
$dashboardId = "DashboardID# here"
$newDashboardName = "Dashboard name"
$apiVersion = "6.0-preview.3"


$uri = "https://examples.org/tfs/${organization}/${project}/_apis/dashboard/dashboards/${dashboardId}?api-version=${apiVersion}"

$personalAccessToken = "mytokenhere"
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($personalAccessToken)"))


$body = @{
    name = $newDashboardName
    dashboardScope = "project"
    description = "Project Dashboard"
    widgets = @()
} | ConvertTo-Json


$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Put -Body $body -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}


$response | ConvertTo-Json
```

Comment: Hi @Mali Miki, would you please let me know whether my answer below is helpful for you? If it is, it's suggested that you accept my answer below according to [How does accepting an answer work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) to let others who have the similar question with you know this answer more clearly. Don't hesitate to let me know if you have any question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the error because it's a team-scoped dashboard but you don't add [groupId](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/dashboard/dashboards/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP#dashboard) in your request header. `groupId` is the ID of the group for a dashboard. For team-scoped dashboards, this is the unique identifier for the team associated with the dashboard. For project-scoped dashboards this property is empty.

Based on my test, we can't directly change the scope of a dashboard. I have tested the REST API [Dashboards - Replace Dashboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/dashboard/dashboards/replace-dashboard?view=azure-devops-server-rest-6.0#dashboardscope) you are using, but it doesn't take effect after changing the `dashboardScope`.

As a workaround, we can create a new dashboard from the copied one with project-scoped.

Request header:

```
POST https://{instance}/{collection}/{project}/{team}/_apis/dashboard/dashboards/{Dashboard ID}?api-version=6.0-preview.3
```

Body:

```
    {
        "copyDashboardScope": 2,
        "projectId": "{Project ID}",
        "teamId": "",
        "name": "{New Dashboard Name}",
        "description": "",
        "refreshInterval": 0,
        "copyQueriesFlag": false,
        "queryFolderPath": "Shared Queries"
}
```